# Determine authorized application that sent Twitter Direct Message?

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to determine the authorized application that sent a direct message using the API?

Documentation is here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/direct_messages but doesn't provide definitions for the fields and not seeing a field that might denote it (of course there are a lot of fields so might have missed it)

I know one of my authorized apps was sending direct message SPAM so want to figure out which one it was.